# In Excel, I need to custom format a cell to show time as hh:mm, but it returns with 0:00

Tags: excel

I would like to be able to enter "1830" into a cell and have Excel automatically convert it to the format 18:30.

I've tried to format cells using custom format and time and I could not get it to work. Please try it yourself before posting all I need to do is enter hh:mm.

Im guessing I will need to use VBA, which I am not very familiar with, but would like to learn. I understand I can right-click on "Sheet1", goto "View Source", and make sure "Worksheet" and not "General" is selected at the top, and code away. If someone can paste the code it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Create this Custom Format and apply to selected cells:  0\:00

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted the current time in excel you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> in a cell and get the time put in the cell

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you must first come up with some rules for for converting integer values into time values.  Some questions:

If someone types 7, do you want to leave that as 7, or do you want to convert it to 00:07?

If someone types 1861, do you want to convert it to 19:01?

If someone types 1830.5, do you want to convert it to 18:30:30?

Comment: +1 for pointing out some pitfalls of subverting Excel's input rules

Answer (score 2):

This will only affect A1, but you can change rAffected to be whatever range you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rAffected As Range

    'You may want to limit which cells change
    Set rAffected = Me.Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rAffected) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = TimeSerial(Left$(Target.Value2, Len(Target.Value2) - 2), Right$(Target.Value2, 2), 0)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I don't understand why the OP is so obsessed with not typing ":", perhaps his keyboard is missing a key, but you deserve some rep. for humouring him!

Comment: Agreed.  I voted up your answer before I added mine.  I have to admit, I have some quirky annoyances/shortcuts that I've coded for myself that other people would think are strange.  So I try not judge to harshly - out loud anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. You just type 18:30 into a cell and Excel does the rest for you.

Comment: Right, but I would have to manually put the colon in there everytime. I want to be able to type 1830 without a colon and have excel add the colon automatically. (Its for a computer lab that asks users to type in what time they checked in, so they can limit use to 30 min)

Comment: @Tom That's how Excel want's you to do it. It actually stores it as fractions of a whole day so 12:00 is stored as 0.5 and just presented as a time. Life will be loads easier if you just roll with Excel and do what it wants you to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need. User inputs 24hr time using the numeric keypad, and colon entry was a pain in the butt...

This is kind of overkill but it works for my situation. All you need to do is format the cells you want using one of the 24 hour time formats:

```
  Public Sub Handle24HourTimeEntry(ByVal Target As Range)
   'Converts up to 4 digits to 24 hour time
   Dim sTime24 As String

   Const sTIME_FORMATS As String = "|h:mm;@|h:mm|hh:mm|"
   Const sERROR_VALUE As String = "XXXX"
   'Valid 24hr time values: 1, 59, 135, 2035, 2359
   'Invalid values: 2400, 90, 9999, 12345

     If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then ' ensure that only single cell edits get processed
        If IsNumeric(Target.Cells.Value2) Then ' skips empty cells, labels and error conditions
           If Not Target.Cells.HasFormula Then ' skip formulas
              If InStr(1, sTIME_FORMATS, "|" & Target.Cells.NumberFormat & "|") > 0 Then
                 If Target.Value2 >= 1 Then ' it's not a standard time value
                    sTime24 = Format$(Target.Value2, "0000")
                    If Len(sTime24) = 4 Then
                       sTime24 = Left$(sTime24, 2) & ":" & Mid$(sTime24, 3, 2)
                       If IsDate(sTime24) Then
                          Target.Value2 = CDate(sTime24)
                       Else
                          Target.Value = sERROR_VALUE
                       End If
                    Else
                       Target.Value = sERROR_VALUE
                    End If
                 End If
              End If
           End If
        End If
     End If

  End Sub
```

I call it from the workbook sheet change event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

   Handle24HourTimeEntry Target

End Sub
```